# Force decimal places in Excel

Tags: excel

I have cells that contain one or two numbers inside, that may have decimal part. When 2 numbers are in the cell, I want that the numbers match the decimal places (according to the number that has the most ones). Examples:

1,67 to 2 meters
2 to 3,1 meters maximum
1,999 to 2,1 cm

I want:

1,67 to 2,00 meters
2,0 to 3,1 meters maximum
1,999 to 2,100 cm

The decimal part (when exists) is separated by a ",". The numbers are separated with other numbers or text by a space. When there is only one number nothing is done to the displaying (there is no numbers to compare)

How can this be done? (Custom formatting? conditional rule? Macro?)

Comment: To clarify: Your cells contain text strings, they contain not numbers. The text strings contain characters, that are digits. Where do the text strings come from? I suspect, they were built by concatenating text and numbers. If so, then the formatting of the numbers should have done while this concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your issue, but if you know the number of decimals, you can store the first value in one column, the second value in a second column and in a third column have your result calculated by a text formula (see below):

Say you want 3 decimals, and you have your first value in A1, your second in B1:

> =TEXT(A1,"0.000")&" to "&TEXT(B1,"0.000")